# Getting (almost) the same results when running AS inspections and gradle Lint

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, lint

I have a similar issue [than this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897682/difference-between-running-lint-via-android-studio-menu-and-gradlew-command-line). I want to get the same results (as much as possible) when running code inspections from Android Studio and from a console Gradle task.
When running from AS, I am using an xml Profile that defines some inspection tools, e.g:

```
<inspection_tool class="AndroidLintContentDescription" enabled="false" level="WARNING" enabled_by_default="false" />
<inspection_tool class="AndroidLintHardcodedText" enabled="true" level="INFO" enabled_by_default="true" />
<inspection_tool class="AndroidLintRegistered" enabled="true" level="INFO" enabled_by_default="true" />
<inspection_tool class="AnonymousClassComplexity" enabled="true" level="WARNING" enabled_by_default="true">
```

I am having big differences in results from AS and console (78 items in AS "Android Lint" section vs. 38 items in the console).
How can I load this Profile when running Lint from console? Is this even possible?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Lint is only a subset of the inspections that you can run in Android Studio/IntelliJ. If you want the same results in both, you should disable any non-Android-Lint inspections in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks Scott. So, in order to get *all* the inspections defined in my Profile, I must run them from inside Android Studio?

Answer (score 4):

You can run the Android Studio inspections from command line:

```
<android studio path>/bin/inspect.sh
```

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-inspections-offline.html

Comment: I'm running Android Studio 1.3.2 on Windows 8.1 and I don't see that shell file. Sounds strange to run a sh script from Windows, anyway...

Comment: It should be inspect.bat in windows. See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-inspections-offline.html